# Wait for an EC2 instance to reboot

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Most actions you can do on an instance are synchronous – for instance, if you send a [stop request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TEC2StopInstancesRequestNET45.html), it will be ran immediately and the program will block until it's completed.

[RebootInstanceRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TEC2RebootInstancesRequestNET45.html), however, just schedule a reboot to be done later.

Is there a way to access the schedule of an instance to know a reboot is planned, or in some other way to wait until the reboot is complete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if you send a stop request, it will be ran immediately and the program will block until it's completed

Not true. When you issue a `ec2:StopInstance` request, the instance moves from a `running` to `stopping` state. But your program does not block. The request returns immediately returning the updated instance state. If you want to determine when the EC2 instance is finally in a `stopped` state, then you need to poll the EC2 instance state using `ec2:DescribeInstances`.

As for reboot requests, once requested, a reboot happens nearly immediately. As your link mentions, if a Linux instance is not rebooted within 4 minutes, AWS ends up forcing a hard reboot.

Since a reboot happens within the EC2 instance hardware, the state of the EC2 instance does not change from `running`. There is no `rebooting` state. And there is no mechanism to determine when the OS of your EC2 instance starts and/or completes it's reboot other than monitoring messages in the EC2 instance console log.

Pretty much the best you can do is issue the reboot request and assume/hope that it's rebooted in the next few minutes.

As an alternative, you can stop and restart the instance:

1. Issue a stop request,
2. Wait for the instance to stop,
3. Issue a start request,
4. Wait for the instance to be running.

Comment: Right, thank you. The start/stop method costs another billing hour, so I guess I'll just try with timing. Thanks again!